# In C++, how to let a (nested) compare functor refer to data of the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, caching, comparator, functor, nested-class

I want to design a custom compare functor for std::set, which uses cached values of the enclosing class (in which the set is defined).

I know that in C++, there is no direct access from the nested class to the enclosing class and that you need to store a pointer in the nested class (as several questions/answers on SO already nicely explained).

But my question is how do you import such a pointer (pModel in my code skeleton) in a comparison functor ?

My code skeleton:

```
using namespace std;
class Face;

class Model
{
public:
    // ...
    map<Face, double> areaCached;

    double area(Face f)
    {
        if (areaCached.find(f) == areaCached.end())
        {
            double calculatedValue;  //  perform very expensive calculation
            areaCached[f] = calculatedValue;
        }
        return areaCached[f];
    }

    struct CompareByArea
    {
        // how can I import the pModel pointer here?

        bool operator() (const Face f1, const Face f2) const
        {
            return pModel->area(f1) <  pModel->area(f2);
        }
    };

    set<Face, CompareByArea> sortedFaces;

};
```

Comment: I hope you understand that Model change will invalidate `sortedFaces` set and you would need to clear it and fully recreate?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.. any model change can add faces or change the area of the faces. So model changes need to invalidate all kind of cached information (such as sortedFaces).. but thanks for pointing out anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different associative containers take a comparison object as a constructor parameter. That is, you'd add a pointer to your comparison function and add a constructor setting this pointer. Then you construct you set correspondingly:

```
class Model {
    struct CompareByArea {
        Model* model;
        CompareByArea(Model* model): model(model) {}
        bool operator()(Face const& f1, Face const& f2) const {
            return model->area(f1) < model->area(f2);
        }
    };
    std::set<Face, CompareByArea> sortedFaces;
    // ...
public:
    Model(): sortedFaces(CompareByArea(this)) {}
    // ...
};
```

The use of `this` may issue warnings about use of `this` before it is fully constructed but as long as `this` isn't use in constructor of `CompareByArea` to access the `Model` there isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I give you an example with references, just because I prefer them to pointers.

```
struct CompareByArea
{
    CompareByArea(Model& aModel):model(aModel)

    bool operator() (const Face& f1, const Face& f2) const
    {
        return model.area(f1) <  model.area(f2);
    }

    Model& model;
};
```

And you should priviledge references over pointers in C++. It's easier to read and understand.

Comment: Yes, but how should I define my set now? (Does the constructor of a std::set not expect a default constructor for the functor?)

Comment: You forgot & in `Model model;` member

Comment: @StephaneRolland irony is this is an argument why not to use reference here, you introduced unnecessary object copy (unless Model is prohibited to copy) and detect it could be difficult, but with pointers it would not compile.

Comment: @Slava okay for passing Face objects as references too.